# Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed error in ROS

Tags: python, ubuntu, arduino, ros

I'm new to ROS I want to connect ROS to Arduino. I googled how to do it and I got a tutorial from this [ROS Wikis page](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup).I followed what they had told but when I try to run the `catkin_make` command, I'm getting this error

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/anant/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:168 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/anant/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/anant/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:320: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I googled a lot but couldn't find any solution on how to solve it.So please help me solve this issue.

**System Information**

```
OS - Ubuntu 18.04 installed in Virtual Box on Windows 10
ROS - Melodic Morenia
```